# Call a function in another Marionette.ItemView

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have one ItemView, where I use clearSearch() function. I need to call the same function in another ItemView, so to keep it DRY I tried to call clearSearch(), but i didn't work.

```
View.Panel = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: panelTpl,
    events: {
        'click .search_clear': 'clearSearch',
    }
    clearSearch: function() {
        //some important actions
    }
});

View.Pagination = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: paginationTpl,
    events: {
        'click .page': 'changePage'
    },
    changePage: function(e) {
        //others important actions
        clearSearch();
    }
});
```

I also tried to use `View.Panel.clearSearch()`, but I've got this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){return i.apply(this,arguments)}
>   has no method 'clearSearch'

.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use events.

define a global event bus:

```
Event.Dispatcher = _.clone(Backbone.Events);
```

and in your pagination view.

```
View.Pagination = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: paginationTpl,
  events: {
    'click .page': 'changePage'
  },
  changePage: function(e) {
    //notify page change event
    Event.Dispatcher.trigger("pageChanged", [pass any data you want to pass]);
  }
});
```

in your panel view, listen to this event, and define how to handle it.

```
View.Panel = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: panelTpl,
  events: {
    'click .search_clear': 'clearSearch',
  },
  initialize: function() {
    //listen to that event
    this.listenTo(Event.Dispatcher, 'pageChanged', this.clearSearch);
  },
  clearSearch: function() {
    //some important actions
  }
});
```

I don't have any experience with Marionette. There may be easier ways to implement this with Marionette, but this is the pattern I've been using in my pure vanilla backbone applications.

Answer (score 2):

With Marionette you can also use [Triggers](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.view.md#viewtriggers) that fire events on that view. For example:

```
View.Panel = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: panelTpl,
    triggers: {
       'click .search_clear': 'panel:clearSearch'
    }
});

myPanel.on('panel:clearSearch', function(args){
    //some important actions
});
```