# alert window in a different view after form submit using backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, backbone.js

Using backbone.js, and I have a form that I am able to submit and after submitting, the savepost() function redirects it to the dashboard url. The dashboard is a different view, and would like that page to say "your post was submitted". I could use localstorage, but do not want to depend on it.

I also see the popular [event aggregator options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205707/passing-data-from-one-backbone-view-to-another/20358509#20358509), but not sure if that would work on views being rendered in the a different page.

[image]

Comment: There's nothing wrong with depending on `localStorage`. It's widely supported. You can also use cookies or check via a request on the second view.

Comment: Thank you Onur, I forgot about the cookies. Much appreciate the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need a global event bus.

Here's a great example jsfiddle, author is credited in the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/JamesOR/m8J9L/

```
var eventBus = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
```

Then, inside the dashboard view, listen for the event. In the fiddle you'll notice the author uses `.on`. This is old style, the backbone author now recommends `listenTo`, because once the view is removed, all listeners are removed automatically. This is not the case with `on`

```
initialize: function () {
    this.listenTo(eventBus,'formSubmitted',this.onFormSubmit);
}
```

Then, when the form is submitted, trigger the event.

```
eventBus.trigger('formSubmitted', /** data that you want to send to handler*/);
```

In the handler method

```
onFormSubmit:function(/** data that sent to this handler*/){
    //code here
}
```