# backbone event not bound to dynamically added content

Tags: jquery, events, backbone.js

I'm trying to bind some click events to a sidebar I dynamically add to the dom and slide it from the outer left into the view (left aligned). It works fine, but events are not working inside the sidebar.

This is views code:

```
define(function (require) {
    "use strict";

    var $ = require('jquery'),
        _ = require('underscore'),
        Backbone = require('backbone'),
        Mustache = require('mustache'),
        optionstpl = require('text!tpl/misc/options.html'),
        options = Mustache.compile(optionstpl);

    return Backbone.View.extend({
        events: {
            'click .homebtn': 'homebtn'
        },

        initialize: function () {
            this.opened = false;
        },

        toggleOptions: function (event) {
            if (!this.opened) {
                var page = $('<div></div>').attr('class', 'page page-left transition options').html(options());
                this.setElement(page);
                $('#container').append(this.$el);
                $('#container')[0].offsetWidth;
                this.$el.removeClass('page-left');
                this.events['click .homebtn'] = 'homebtn';
                this.delegateEvents();
                this.opened = true;
            } else {
                $('.page.options').one('webkitTransitionEnd', function (e) {
                    $(e.target).remove();
                }).addClass('page-left');
                this.opened = false;
            }
        },

        homebtn: function (e) {
            alert('homebtn pressed');
            this.toggleOptions(e);
            ee.Routers.mainRouter.navigate('');
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see, the element is not added to the DOM when the view is initialized. Because that sidebar should only show up when I click some button on my page, that is why I call toggleOptions from another view which acts as a parent view to this one. Showing and hiding this sidebar works fine, but my click event which should fire the homebtn function is not working at all. On toggle I dynamically create the new element with jquery and assign it as the new 'el' using setElement, then I add it to the DOM and call delegateEvents to get my events bound to it, but it seems this is not working. What am I doing wrong here?

PS: As you can see in the else block, I remove the sidebar after it moved out of the view, that is why I recreate it and call delegateEvents to get my lost events again. But even if I open the sidebar once and click the homebutton, nothing happens. So my events to get even bound to it.

Comment: Why don't you show us your `options` template? Do you see any error in browser's console?

Comment: how are you rendering the view?

Comment: My options template is a simple ul with some li elements. Oneof them has the homebtn class. No errors in my console at all.

Comment: As you can see in my toggleOptions function i load the options.html file with require into a mustache handler and render it directly into a dynamically created div element which i then add to the main container to slide it into the view with 3d transitions using css3. This part works fine. Only problem is my events object is not bound to that options container. I don't see any problem in my code. But note when this view is loaded the options container does not exist. It will be created when i click the options button which is handled by another view calling toggleOptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm...not really sure what's the problem here, but I made a simple jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ezH4R/

there's a small problem with your code:

```
var page = $('<div></div>').attr('class', 'page page-left transition options').html(options());
this.setElement(page);
$('#container').append(this.$el);
```

so when you call `this.setElement(page)` the `el` of your view will be switched to `page` which is a `div`. all your view elements will be delegated on that `div` as well. (by the way I dont think you need to assign events manually after calling `setElement`.) so, when next time `toggleOptions` is called again, (if opened === false) you are gonna create div, set the view's `el` to the new one, and then append it to the `#container`. I don't see where(or if) the old div is removed/destroyed, but the view is gonna `unDelegate` the events on the old div.

so when you remove '.page.options' you are actually removing the `el` of the view! I think we will need to see the part where bring the view back, maybe that's why your code is not working. Could you post that code please?

Comment: there is not much to add. there is only another view which is i set the el property manually to the container having the option button. then in its events objects i point to that option button to catch the click. when clicked it calls the toggleOptions function of the upper view. i stored that view globally in a variable so the buttons view has access to it. thats it. i think closing the options view is not the problem, because im not getting that far when testing. i open it, then click on my home button which should pop up my alert, but it doesn't. i think because its dynamically added.

Comment: dynamically adding element should not be an issue, backbone uses jquery's `delegate` on the view's `el` to bind events - the events will work as long as they are under the `el`. Could you check what's the `el` of your view after homebtn is rendered? and I'd not recommend using `setElement` a lot to alter the el of your view. Also, I'd suggest you to refactor your implementation of the views, usually you don't want to reference another view(as a global!) in any of your views.

Comment: It sounds like there's a much easier way to do it, by using the subscriber/publisher pattern, render both of your views - the button view, and the menu view - then when the button view is clicked, publish the event to the global event channel, and your menu view should subscribe to this event, when it is triggered, show itself, so you don't have to remove/add it in the DOM or to `setElement` of your view. a simple example can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227151/how-to-bind-context-of-child-view-handling-event-in-parent-view/20229101#20229101

Comment: i will definitely use that pattern, sounds good. i was thinkin about having my options view loaded already in the dom. but the problem is my app runs on a phone using phonegap (incl. as a mobile web app) and whenever i have another div container in the view, it happens that i can scroll my view in any direction if there is another one loaded out of the view which is kinda annoying. that is why i usually slide out views and remove them when i jump to another view, works great, but my only problem is the view loaded dynamically.

Comment: i had a typo in my html and i used your pattern. its much easier now. and finally my code works. thanks.