# Backbone main view control

Tags: backbone.js

I have a main section of code that initialises of all my views. How should I handle / listen / bind events from the main sections (probably will turn this into a main app view eventually) with elements of these initialised views? I could pass a reference of a view into another view and do something from inside that view but I'd rather have all this logic in the main / parent. Is this possible or good practice?

Answer (score 0):

If they are all DOM events. No, each view should handle it's own DOM events.

If one view needs to know if something is happening in another view...well, there're lots of ways to do it. I'd usually prefer the subscriber/publisher pattern.

See my answer to another question for code examples: 
[Call a function in another Marionette.ItemView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181679/call-a-function-in-another-marionette-itemview/20182584#20182584)

You do not need Marionette for that.